# Developing with Sass, keeping the compiled file out of git

Tags: css, sass

I have a very large project with many contributors. A lot of whom don't work on the sass or front end.

Currently we have a deployment pipeline which will compile the sass and deploy it to a staging server. However I still have to compile the sass locally and commit compiled sass files into the repo otherwise the other developers won't see the changes. This creates the problem of the files constantly conflicting.

Ideally I would like to find a way to serve the sass files without having to compile sass every time. Any ideas?

Comment: You have to compile Sass files before you serve them, that's kinda how things work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe in your server you can set up a sass watcher via console that detects the changes in the sass files and compiles them by itself once you upload them.

Here you can read more about it:
http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#using_sass

Comment: Everyone is running their own vagrant server, i perhaps could add something to the chef script to automatically run a watcher.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply push your sass files to your repo and whoever wants to view the changes, compile the sass on his end.

Comment: I could do that through a git hook, however it will then require everyone on the project to set up a git hook.